# Batch Script is not getting the correct server name?

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch script to query the server, but when i initiate it, the servername won't appear. I don't know why.

Here's the script:

```
set reg1=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VERITAS\NetBackup\CurrentVersion
FOR /F %%i in (%server%) do reg query \\%%i\%reg1%/v %valueName% |FINDSTR  "Install Type" >>%LogFiel%

FOR /F "tokens=4,5* delims= " %%z in (%LogFile%) do echo The %%i %%z Master >r.txt
```

Results was:
`%i Master`

I tried to use if else but still not get the %%i which is the servername.

---

Hi Mark here's the script

```
set WorkingDir=D:\Patching\Uptime\Uptime
set LogFile=%WorkingDir%\Status1.log
set LogFile1=%WorkingDir%\Status2.log
set server=list.txt
set valueName="Install Type"
set reg1=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VERITAS\NetBackup\CurrentVersion notepad.exe
FOR /F %%i in (%server%) do reg query \\%%i\%reg1% /v %valueName% |FINDSTR "Install Type" >>%LogFiel%
FOR /F "tokens=4,5* delims= " %%z in (%LogFile%) do echo The %%i %%z Master >r.txt pause –
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1. `%server%` isn't defined in this script.
2. `%valueName%` isn't defined in this script
3. You reference `%LogFiel%` in the second line, but `%LogFile%` in the next
4. You're referring to `%%i` outside of its loop, so it's no longer defined.
5. Your `reg query` will expand out to `\\servername\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VERITAS\NetBackup\CurrentVersion/v` and should have a space before the /v

I suspect that it's #4 that's causing the most obvious problem, but can you post the rest of your script?  It doesn't look like this is the whole thing.

**Edit:** I meant #4 was causing the problem - forgot I added a line above it. :-)

Comment: Hi Mark here's the script set WorkingDir=D:\Patching\Uptime\Uptime
set LogFile=%WorkingDir%\Status1.log
set LogFile1=%WorkingDir%\Status2.log
set server=list.txt

set valueName="Install Type" 

set reg1=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VERITAS\NetBackup\CurrentVersion 



notepad.exe 

FOR /F %%i in (%server%) do reg query \\%%i\%reg1% /v %valueName% |FINDSTR  "Install Type" >>%LogFiel%
FOR /F "tokens=4,5* delims= " %%z in (%LogFile%) do echo The %%i %%z Master >r.txt
pause

Comment: i would like the results server Netbackup Master. but it only gives me %i Netbackup.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add the entire script (rather than posting it as an answer). As a side note, I'm not sure what notepad.exe is in there for...

Comment: notepad.exe is for adding the target server then it would save as list.txt.